# How to make a column in a dataframe have a given number of digits

Tags: r

I need some of the variables of my dataframe to have a given number of digits. In this case, I need "st" variable to have 2 digits and "county" variable to have 3 digits.

Let's say I have this dataframe:

```
state(Alabama, Alabama, Alabama, Alabama, Alabama, Alabama)
st(3,5,7,9,11,13)
county(7, 33, 15, 17, 111, 189)
state_county <- data.frame(state, st, county)
```

Thanks!
And I want to get this:

```
state(Alabama, Alabama, Alabama, Alabama, Alabama, Alabama)
st(03,05,07,09,11,13)
county(007, 033, 015, 017, 111, 189)
state_county1 <- data.frame(state, st, county)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you give isn't syntactically correct, but assuming the dataframe you start with is this:

```
state_county <- data.frame(
  state = rep("Alabama", 6),
  st = c(3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13),
  county = c(7, 33, 15, 17, 111, 189)
)
```

You can write a function that adds a specified number of zeros to the relevant elements in a vector, and then apply this to each of your columns:

```
convert_digits <- function(x, digits) {
  len <- nchar(as.character(x))
  zeros <- sapply(digits-len[len < digits], function(x) paste0(rep(0, x), collapse = ""))
  x[len < digits] <- paste0(zeros, x[len < digits])
  return(x)
}

state_county$st <- convert_digits(state_county$st, 2)
state_county$county <- convert_digits(state_county$county, 3)
```